# How to get alt in image url?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I only get the alt attribute of the a p tag in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256189/how-can-i-only-get-the-alt-attribute-of-the-a-p-tag-in-php)

I have a the following HTML code:

```
<img src="test.png" alt="test1" />
<img src="test2.png" alt="test2" />
```

How to get the value of the `alt`-attribute from these `img`-tags ? Any ideas for implementing a function `getAlt()`?

Comment: Best way to parse HTML with PHP - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-way-to-parse-html-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DomDocument` class. 
I do [this example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9VHeSZ) that exports the info to an array.

**Code**:

```
<?php

    // HTML Content
    $html = '
        <img src="test.png" alt="test1" />
        <img src="test2.png" alt="test2" />
    ';

    $dom = new DomDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($html);

    $alts = array();

    $tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach($tags as $tag) {
        $alts[$tag->attributes->getNamedItem('src')->nodeValue] = $tag->attributes->getNamedItem('alt')->nodeValue;
    }

    // DEBUG
    foreach($alts as $key => $alt) {
        echo "{$key} => {$alt}<br/>";
    }

?>
```